# Setting PPI For a web template

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I want to create a template . If the user monitor at least is 14 inches , It has a ppi for itself maybe 102 or something else.

So What ppi should I set for my web template to avoid the screen horizontal scrolling ? Is it the maximum ppi of the 14 inches monitor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ppi/dpi (dots per inch) doesn't work here: Different 14 inch monitors can have different resolutions - the number of pixels displayed on the screen.

For your purposes, the only thing you need to worry about is the user's resolution.

The size of a pixel can differ depending on the device's size, but it doesn't matter for layouting.

If you want to avoid scroll bars, either choose a very low pixel width (960 pixels is deemed ideal by many, because layouts with that width are guaranteed to work on a 1024 x 768 resolution) or use relative widths instead of pixel sizes.

Related:

- Smashing Magazine: [Fixed vs. Fluid vs. Elastic Layout: What’s The Right One For You?](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/)

Comment: Should also add that 960 is not just an arbitrary number < 1024, it's also neatly divisible (for instance 12 x 80-pixel columns, or 12 x 60px columns with 20px gutters, etc.) -- see http://960.gs/ for "proof" :)